# Add Linux partition entry to boot menu (UEFI Windows 10)

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, kali-linux

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for a while and all I have found is that it can't be done. I was wondering if any of you might have a solution.

Here is a bullet list of what I have installed:

- I have a laptop that is running Windows 10
- I partitioned the disk so that I have a D disk just for Linux
- I installed Linux Debian
- I tried starting the new OS from the Boot Option Menu, however there was no entry
- I tried using easy BCD, however it does not work with UEFI boot.

Comment: Try with [EasyUEFI](http://easyuefi.com/index-us.html)

Comment: @Biswa it does not work as the partition is on my second hard disk and EasyUEFI does not seem to be able to access that partition

Comment: See my discussion https://discuss.howtogeek.com/t/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/60141

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.